# with "error during template rendering"

Tags: django

I have some problems about template in django. Following the instruction of Django2.0 document, i am facing with this problem.

> Error during template rendering
>
> Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['main_app\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']

**results.html**

```html
<h1>{{question.question_text}}</h1>
<ul>
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote {{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'main_app:detail' question.id %}">Vote again!!</a>
```

**detail.html**

```html
<h1>{{question.question_text}}</h1>
{% if error_message %}
<p>
  <strong>
    {{error_message}}
  </strong>
</p>
{% endif %}
<form class="" action="{% url 'main_app:votes' question.id %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{choice.id}}"/>
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{choice.choice_text}}</label><br/>
    <!-- forloop.counter indicates how many times the for tag has gone through its loop-->
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Vote"/>
</form>
```

**main_app/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Question,Choice
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    lastest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:5]
    context={'lastest_question_list':lastest_question_list}
    return render(request,'main_app/index.html',context)
def detail(request,question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=question_id)
    context = {'question':question}
    return render(request,'main_app/detail.html',context)
def results(request,question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=question_id)
    context = {'queston':question}
    return render(request,'main_app/results.html',context)
def votes(request,question_id):
    question=get_object_or_404(Question,pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request,'main_app/detail.html',{
            'question':question,
            'error_message':"You didn't select a choice",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main_app:results',args=
         (question.id,)))
```

**main_app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'main_app'
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/',views.detail,name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/',views.results,name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/votes/',views.votes,name='votes'),
]
```

Is there anything wrong or lacking something!! Please help
I am new for django.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you need to add `question_id = question.id`. But apparently here `question` is not part of the context, or it has no `id`.

Comment: Please add `results.html`  anywhere that you have an `url`

Answer (score -1):

Your `results` view doesn't define the `question` object in the context:

```
context = {'queston':question}
```